# Can someone tell me why this doesn't work? C# XNA

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

So I made this method for spawning mobs with a time delay in between, the problem is that the condition goes through but it doesn't want to access what's inside.

```
    public void CreateMonsterWave(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spawnDelay += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            if (spawnDelay >= 2f && creepAmountOut < monsterWave.Length) 
            {
                spawnDelay = 0f;
                monsterWave[creepAmountOut] = new WaveMonster(monsterHp, monsterDamage, monsterTex, waveStartPos, path1);
                creepAmountOut++;
            } 
    }

      //In LoadContent
      monsterWave = new WaveMonster[8];
```

I'm pretty new to coding so it feels like I'm missing something fundamental...

Comment: use breakpoint to see if value of variable inside your condition.

Comment: 0.01666667. But does the code have any errors otherwise?

Comment: What do you mean by, *"the condition goes through"*? There are two parts to the condition. Can you confirm that `spawnDelay >= 2`? And that `creepAmountOut < monsterWave.Length`?  Also, what do you mean by *"it doesn't want to access what's inside"*? What is *it*? Inside *what*? The array?

Comment: Ok, since the condition never became true in the first place it had to cycle until it does become true. But my draw method can't draw an empty array so I solved it by placing a bool right after creepAmountOut++. Thanks for making me realize the problem.

Comment: Sorry @RufusL my terminology is lacking everything doesn't pop immediately into my head, I meant inside the if statement.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You mentioned that `spawnDelay` was `0.01666667`. That is clearly less than `2f`, which means your first condition is `false`, and the `if` block won't execute. What exactly is the question..? If you wait a few more seconds and call this method again (so that `spawnDelay` will be `> 2`) what happens?

Comment: The original problem was that the program stopped because it couldn't draw an empty array. So I assumed it was something wrong with this method, but in fact, it just hasn't gone through the condition yet to create the objects in the array. I called it in Update so it would eventually reach >= 2f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the condition of your if statement ensuring that the "spawnDelay" is greater or equal to 2f and the "creepAmountOut" is less than the "monsterWave.length". You can use a messagebox or something before the if statement to display this data to ensure that everything evaluates to a true condition of that if statement.